# How to find the plane a FDR came from?

Tags: flight-data-recorder, boeing-767

I'm trying to find out which plane a Sundstrand UFDR came from and have narrowed it down to 5 possible planes.   How can I confirm which of the 5 planes the FDR recorder came from?

I did a lot of research and found out that Boeing had a contract to install Sundstrand UFDRs into their 767 and 757 planes.

The Sundstrand UFDR in question has one of the tags stating "BOEING PART NUMBER" instead of "CUSTOMER PART NUMBER" and a date code of 8822, made the 22nd week of 1988.  It also has two SAS identification tags on it, from SAS airline.

From SAS annual reports archived on their website, they stated they had ordered five 767s, and indeed five 767-383ERs were delivered to SAS from Boeing in 1989.

SAS no longer owns any of these 767s, 2 are listed as still active, one as stored and 2 are listed as having been scrapped, one scrapped in 2010, and the other in 2017.

My research also shows that this particular model UFDR, would have had to be removed from all planes it was in, by Jan 1st, 2016, as all such magnetic tape FDRs had to be replaced with digital chip technology.

Now the ONE 767 in this group was scrapped, while a UFDR would have still been allowed.   The other plane was scrapped after it would already have had the newer digital chip storage FDR in it.

What typically happened to these Sundstrand UFDRs in 2016 when they were removed from planes and replaced with the newer ones?

Where and how does one go about finding records on which serial number FDR was on a particular serial number Boeing plane?

Being I have narrowed it down to 5 planes, how do I now confirm which of the 5 planes it came from?

Comment: You would need the maintenance records of each of those aircraft to determine this.  Good luck!

Comment: Equipment like that isn't necessarily on a single aircraft, only.  The airline would probably have a small stock of FDR's, and if one malfunctions or otherwise needs to be swapped out, one from stock would replace the one from the aircraft.  And when that one is repaired, checked & good to go, it returns to stock, waiting to be similarly installed. So the box you have may well have been in more than 1 of the 5 jets at some point. And without the records tracking removals & installations by serial #, there's probably no way to know which one(s).

Comment: I figured it could have been moved at some point, especially once after the planes were in possession of other airlines, (which brings up the question, would they leave the SAS control number tag on it, or remove that and put their own airline tag on it) but as Boeing put these on the 767s when building them, at least it would be nice to know which plane it started on.

Then if I find a photo of its first flight, I know it was on that plane.    Hard to say if it stayed on that plane, unless I can find an accident report from an airline that had it after SAS, with the serial number on it.

Comment: Would maintenance records still exist from 1989 - 2016?  And do they follow the plane to subsequent airlines, or stay with the airlines, and new records kept with a new airline from the point they get the plane?

I also wonder if Boeing still has records from planes they put together around 1988-1989.

Comment: Such records certainly could exist, but they are definitely not in the "public domain."  It's possible the right person the the maintenance department at SAS or Boeing could find this out, but it could be quite the project to find & persuade that person to spend the necessary time and effort. If it'd be allowed at all.

Comment: Boeing will have records dating from the earliest 767, and maintenance records will also exist. They'll be needed for accident investigation, if nothing else. And given @RalphJ 's comment above, it's quite possible that your FDR was always a spares-stock item, and wasn't installed on any aircraft at delivery.

Comment: When it was removed from the original plane, I don't know, but it was indeed the original UFDR put on a new 767-383ER when Boeing delivered it to SAS.

This one has the unique luck of the link between Boeing, the model UFDR, and the contract between those two companies and all 767s, the SAS tags on it, and the year date code matching when SAS got five new 767s from Boeing.

If not for the link of all of those things matching perfectly, I would not have been able to determine it was an original from 1 of 5 planes. 

Now for some luck to narrow it down to 1.

Comment: I'm still also trying to find out how these used flight data recorders come into the public market.   From scrapped planes?  Or are they kept by the airline before being left at the boneyards?   When they become obsolete technology and required to be replaced, (like this model was by 2016) do the airlines sell them to used aircraft part dealers?  The Underwater Locator Beacon was removed.  Perhaps because it was still good and just put on the new FDR that replaced it?   Not sure if this is a helpful clue or not, being sometimes you find them still with the flight recorders.

Comment: Another interesting clue from Lauda Air, who ordered a Boeing 767-3Z9ER that was delivered on 16 Oct 1989, and crashed 26 May 1991, in the crash report lists the Sundstrand UFDR (BXUS) serial number as 5632, close enough to the SAS one.

So this plane had the same flight recorder in it almost 2 years later, that came with the plane from Boeing.

One of the five 767 planes SAS originally had, had an accident after another airline owned it, but there is no mention of the serial number in the report.   This could have verified or eliminated that plane from my search.

Still searching.